# Retrive data using Caml Query Join Operation

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part

How can I retrieve data from two SharePoint List using Join CamlQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope these links will help you out,

http://yogeshlotlikar.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/caml-query-joins/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/01/20/sharepoint-2010-caml-list-joins.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://cawl4sharepoint.com/cawl4sharepoint/cawl_querybuilder/

cawl_QueryBuilder cawl = new cawl_QueryBuilder();
cawl.Select("Users_Title");
cawl.Select("Users_Age");
cawl.Select("Users_Sex");
cawl.Select("CarBrand");
cawl.Join("UsersList";"OwnerColumn");
cawl.Get('UserCarsList');

StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (SPListItem item in cawl.ListItemCollection())
{
  Result.Append(item["Users_Title"].ToString() +
                 item["Users_Age"].ToString() +
                 item["Users_Sex"].ToString() +
                 item["CarBrand"].ToString());

}
Label1.Text = Result .ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You should try using SPSiteDataQuery for Join Operation..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx